# Outputcatching with SQLDependency not working on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, outputcache, sqldependency

I am working on output caching SqlDependency with the help of this [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Cache-Exploration-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Part-1.aspx#s9-using-sqldependency-together-with-outputcache).
I have followed all the given steps and it is working fine when i am running the site through VS2010 but after publishing the site over IIS it seems that SqlDependency is not working because it is always showing the cached page.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link - [blogpost](http://sdeu.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/activate-asp-net-mvc3-caching-with-database-dependency/). I tripped a couple of times in the implementation, but that was due to mis-naming config tags.